# Email notification on Expiry date

Tags: vba, excel

I want to send notification by email on Expiry date this code is sending email 30 days before expiry

```
    Sub reminder4()
 Dim lRow As Integer
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim toDate As Date
 Dim toList As String
 Dim eSubject As String
 Dim eBody As String
 Dim cList As String

 With Application
 .ScreenUpdating = False
 .EnableEvents = False
 .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With
    Sheets(2).Select
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lRow
     toDate = Replace(Cells(i, 3), ".", "/")

        If Left(Cells(i, 5), 4) <> "Mail" And toDate - Date <= 30 Then

     Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
     Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
     Cells(i, 8) = "Mail Sent " & Date + Time
```

It is sending email 30 days before expiry i want to send email upon expiry.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend commenting out `.ScreenUpdating = False`, `.EnableEvents = False`, and `.DisplayAlerts = False` until you get all your code working. You'll find it much, _much_ easier to kill bugs when you can see what's going on. Once everything is working to your satisfaction, re-enable those statements for production work.

Comment: @pnuts its working on current date like in date cells if it is current date it will generate mail if it is yesterday than no mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this line:

```
If Left(Cells(i, 5), 4) <> "Mail" And toDate - Date <= 30 Then
```

with:

```
If Left(Cells(i, 5), 4) <> "Mail" And toDate <= Date Then
```

Comment: when i change toDate= Date its sending only on current date not on expiry if expired yesterday generates no email

Comment: take a quick look at the change on the new line, I replaced `=` with `<=`. I guess it makes sense that you won't be opening the file on weekends, so you'll need to check for things that expired over the weekend, on holidays, etc.

Comment: that is working got another problem its keep on sending as many time as i click button but the 30 days code i post in that case it sends once and write in cell that mail send and not sending again even i click button again when i run this it is writing in cell "mail is sent" but still send again

Comment: That's because you're checking `Cells(i,5)` for the word `Mail` to determine if you want to send it, and when you decide to send it, you're putting `Mail sent <date> <time>` into `Cells(i,8)`. You should either check column **8** for the word `Mail`, or put the word `Mail` into column **5**.